# how to find related css for certain tag in sublimetext2?

Tags: sublimetext2

i have so many tags and classes in my html file. its getting hard to organize them.
in Dreamweaver it was easy to find the related CSS for a specific tag id or class(via CSS pallet)
is there something like this in sublime text 2?
something like this: in the body part i click on a tag and it shows or navigate me to the related css in my css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this plugin : https://github.com/rmaksim/Sublime-Text-2-Goto-CSS-Declaration

To install it, you can firstly install package-control : http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation

Then, using the command shortcut (ctrl+shift+P in my case), you can go to "Package-Control: Install Package" and search for "Goto Css Declaration"

Comment: thanks you
i installed package control but when i search in it, it can not find "goto css..."

Comment: For me, the title is "Goto-CSS-Declaration". Maybe you can install it manually

Comment: i found the way:
Ctrl + Shift+ p -> type "install" and press Enter -> then type goto css ....

Comment: now i installed css selector but dont know how to use it.
it says press super key
what is than on windows keyboard?

Comment: in the picture it shows windows key and right arrow but when i press them the position of the sublime text changes

Comment: answer: windows key + "," which is beside m botton.
the css file has to be opened already
dear Neozaru thanks for you suggetion. that is exactly what i wanted